# Cannot delete Cinder volume with error message "image still has watchers"

Tags: openstack, ceph, openstack-cinder

I run Openstack `cinder` with `ceph` as its storage backend. when I occasionally tried to delete one of cinder-volume, it failed.

So I turned to use `rbd` commands to troubleshoot this issue, below is the error message printed by the command: `rbd rm ${pool}/${volume-id}`

> rbd: error: image still has watchers
> This means the image is still
> open or the client using it crashed. Try again after closing/unmapping
> it or waiting 30s for the crashed client to timeout.

Then `rbd status ${pool}/${volume-id}` shows

> Watchers:
> watcher=172.18.0.1:0/523356342 client.230016780
> cookie=94001004445696

I am confused why the watcher stick on the volume and cause the volume unable to delete, is there any reason or something I did wrong?

And how to delete the volume in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to fix this issue, the concept is adding the watcher to the blacklist by using `ceph osd blacklist`, then the volume will become removable, after deleting, remove the watcher from the blacklist.

1. add the watcher to the blacklist

```
$ ceph osd blacklist add 172.18.0.1:0/523356342
blacklisting 172.18.0.1:0/523356342
```

2. check status and delete the volume

```
$ rbd status ${pool}/${volume-id}
Watchers: none

$ rbd rm ${pool}/${volume-id}
Removing image: 100% complete...done.
```

3. remove the watcher from the blacklist

```
$ ceph osd blacklist rm 172.18.0.1:0/523356342
un-blacklisting 172.18.0.1:0/523356342
```

That's all, but still finding the root cause.